# batch file to copy a folder containing the most recently created file

Tags: copy

Hey guys,
I'm looking for a batch file which will copy a folder and all its contents containing the most recently created file.
I need it to preserve the folder name at the destination aswell.
For example:

If 'c:\test\source\inhere' contains the most recent file, then i would like the 'inhere' directory and all of its contents copied to the destination, c:\test\destination\inhere.

The .bat file would ideally sit in the 'source' folder in the example above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`xcopy` and `if exist` `not exist` would do everything you need eg:-

```
@echo off
xcopy "C:\test\inhere\*.* " c:\mirror\test\inhere\ /c /s /r /d /y /i > c:\mirror\xcopy.log
```

this would copy from inhere (`*.*` means any file extensions could be .pdf or whatever) TO 
IN HERE in a parent folder called mirror. The xcopy.log just writes a log file so you can check

> all was successful